# How can I retrieve the product ID?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to retrieve the product IDs. I can find a product SKU by looking on the product page and using `commerce_product_load_by_sku()` to load it.

How can I find the actual ID? I would like to use it in `commerce_cart_product_add_by_id()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs I [found here](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21cart%21commerce_cart.rules.inc/function/commerce_cart_rules_product_add_by_sku/DC) `commerce_product_load_by_sku($sku)` will return a `$product` object and one of the properties is `product_id`.

```
$product = commerce_product_load_by_sku($sku);
drupal_set_message($product->product_id);
```

The product object looks something like this:

```
[product_id] => 5
[sku] => EX151
[type] => class
[language] => und
[title] => Example Product
[uid] => 1
[status] => 1
[created] => 1316634672
[changed] => 1316639451
[data] => 
[commerce_price] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 12500
                        [currency_code] => USD
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [components] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the id to be retrieved in a function but just for a quick check, do

1. Install module [commerce_backoffice](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), if it is not already part of your Drupal Commerce install.
2. In views, find the view `Commerce Backoffice: All Product variations`. View this view.
3. Hover over a product title. See the product_id as the last part of the corresponding status message in your browser, ie. `example.com/admin/commerce/products/1`.
4. You may want to alter the view by adding a column showing the product_id directly.