# How to obtain a node id and product type from the product variation id?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I have a view in Drupal that has a field called Index product variation search: Item ID. Its description is "the item's internal (search API specific) ID".

Here is an example of what this field looks like:
**entity:commerce_product_variation/111:en**

**What is this number (111)--is it the product_variation id?**

Basically, I am sending in this number through a POST API call (in javascript). I need to use this number to obtain the node id and the product type for a product?

There is something on [How can I retrieve the product ID?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90740/how-can-i-retrieve-the-product-id) but it needs the sku (stock keeping unit) which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the variation entity through entity type manager dependency injection:

```php
$variation = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->load($variationId);
```

Or if you are in a hook:

```php
$variation = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->load($variationId);
```

Then you can retrieve product entity:

```php
$product = $variation->product_id->entity;

// Product id
$productId = $product->id();
// Product type
$productType = $product->bundle();
```

Comment: One quick question: in the example I gave (entity:commerce_product_variation/111:en), the $variationId would be 111, right? Thanks

Comment: Yes thats right